# What is the limit of ongoing HttpWebRequests C#

Tags: c#, .net, windows

our company have it's own benchmark tool to measure performance of api.

Currently I've struggle with list of errors:

```
- The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive.
- The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send.
- The underlying connection was closed: A connection that was expected to be kept alive was closed by the server.
```

At first place I've thinked it is limited by application itself, but provided suggestions to set ServicePointManager properties are already there:

```
ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = false;
ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 20000;
ServicePointManager.UseNagleAlgorithm = false;
```

I'm not sure and cannot find any documentation about limitation on system level - which could give me green light to at least, suggest creating a tool with possibility to create a distributed tests.

Comment: This is not a limitation. All answers indicate the server is just too busy or faulty to return an appropriate answer within time.

Comment: @PatrickHofman Can I set time limit? Server is ok, no exception is thrown during that tests. Also when I check it with jmeter it is able to handle more requests before start failing (~1500 'users')

Comment: You can't see if a server is too busy to accept new requests. What if you try to run the program multiple times in parallel? Same problem?

Comment: @PatrickHofman Ok, it does scale.

Comment: Strange. Did you check the duplicates? Did they help you diagnose the actual problem? There is a lot of useful information in there.

Comment: @PatrickHofman Yes, I did check it,  most of suggestion however I did check before. We are back to investigation currently.